# Why Virtualmin refuses to change the PHP version?

Tags: php, webmin, virtualmin

Ok, after an AWS upgrade, my PHP version abruptly changed from 7.1.8. to 5.4.16. Previously I was using 7.1.8.

To chg back the PHP version to 7.1.8, i tried this. Under Virtualmin -> Server Configurations -> PHP Versions, it says, "This virtual server is using the mod_php or FPM execution mode for PHP, such does not allow per-directory version selection".

So i went to Virtualmin -> System Settings -> Server Templates -> Default -> PHP Options, and selected "Highest Available" but still the PHP version is 5.4.16 (shown my phpinfo output) after Apache restart. Although i have 7.0.27, and 7.1.8. Previously I was using 7.1.8.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Virtualmin i.e. on CentOS, it installs the PHP version from an official repo. The packs have a "u" at the end. Like php70u

My guess is you installed the higher php version from the Remi repo.

I know this because I rendered my server obsolete trying to upgrade my php.

If I'm right, installing a higher "u"-version (they're like 1 edition behind) will solve your problem or completely uninstalling php* and then reinstalling.

I had trouble with delete/reinstall.

You should find out which modules are installed exactly so that you can install them in one batch before you remove because for some reason (I'm not a technical person) php-soap or I think it was php-xml too will give you problems if you add them later.

In any way, delete the repo the old version is pulled from or it will keep re-installing it and mess up your server.